# jqGrid behaving weird with Razor views

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am experiencing weird behavior from my razor views when using jquery.
It would seem as though my views are having there css changed when certain modal windows are loaded?
[image: Original CSS]

[image: Strings are bigger can you see]

I can't begin to tell you why this is happening.  I essentially created the same views using MVC 2 and had little trouble with CSS overloads.  Have any of you experienced similar problems?  Particularly loading Jquery UI and jqGrid with your application?

Comment: It's clear that you have CSS problems, but one can't really solve your problem only taking  look of two pictures. You should *debug* the problem. Just press F12 and start Developer Tools, examine the CSS classes applied to a row (or a cell) of the grid. Then do the same in case of the second picture. You will see which CSS class are removed, changed or which new one overwrite previously correct settings. In the way you can localize the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have the same problem (or very close problem) as the problem described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10936623/315935). So I would recommend to you to add in your CSS either

```css
.ui-jqgrid { font-size: 11px !important; }
```

or alternatively the following CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view { font-size: 11px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager { font-size: 11px; }
.ui-jqgrid .loading { font-size: 11px; }
```

Comment: That was the ticket...  Boy I hate css.