# jqGrid font settings overwritten by jQueryUI tab settings

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282130/wrong-font-size-when-using-jqgrid-inside-jqueryui-tab). I am using jQueryUI tabs to control content on the page, and on some of the tabs I am using jqGrid to display information. The font settings from jqGrid are being overwritten by the larger fonts defined by the tabs. The solution in that example was to define the tab as being of class `ui-jqgrid`. But they didn't have anything except the grids under their tabs, so that solution works. How do I override the font settings for just the grid and allow jqGrid to use its own font settings, but retain the settings for everything else under the tab?

You can see here where it is overwriting my jqGrid font size. I tried using a percentage as well, but it just ignored that too.

[image: CSS Calues]

UPDATED - CSS Computed Style:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to solve the problem. How you can confirm the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287653/315935) works, but it makes other texts to have `11px` font which you don't want.

The problem with the font is the CSS setting (see [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css#L17))

```css
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
```

Because both Tab and jqGrid have the class `"ui-widget"` the setting overwrite the font setting from the jqGrid.css (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.3/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L2)):

```css
.ui-jqgrid {position: relative; font-size:11px;}
```

As the result you have the picture like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInjQueryTab0.htm):

[image]

jQuery UI uses `em` style. So you can for example include in the CSS of your page the following

```css
html, body { font-size: 75% }
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268360/315935)). In the case you will have the following results (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInjQueryTab1.htm)):

[image]

By the way the documentation of jqGrid suggest indirectly (see example of HTML page [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file)). I understand that it could be situations where you want don't change the size of other fonts on the page.

In the case you can use for example

```css
.ui-jqgrid { font-size: 11px !important; }
```

or alternatively the following

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view { font-size: 11px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager { font-size: 11px; }
.ui-jqgrid .loading { font-size: 11px; }
```

The results of the approach you can see on [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInjQueryTab2.htm):

[image]

If I understand you correct it's the results which you want to have.

**UPDATED**: If you use Developer Tools of Chrome you can see the same information as in IE Developer Tools to locate the CSS style which overwrite `font-size` of jqGrid. For example in [my first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInjQueryTab0.htm) you will see

[image]

So if in your application my above suggestions not work you should examine the effective CSS styles aplied to any grid cell and find which CSS setting overwrite CSS of jqGrid.

**UPDATED 2**: From the link which you send me per email I could see that the problem exist because you forgot to include any `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` declaration before `<html>`. So the web browser interpret your page as very old style HTML written in the time before even HTML 3.2 was published (before 1997). It's so named [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

To solve the problem you should include before `<html>` the line like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or just

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

(HTML5 standard). Moreover I strictly recommend you to validate your HTML pages in some HTML valirador like http://validator.w3.org/. You current code is a mix between HTML and XHTML which is not good.

**UPDATED 2**: I posted additionally [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/explicitly-deny-the-usage-of-jqgrid-in-quirk-mode/#p26754) where I suggest to stop creating of jqGrid in case of `document.documentMode <= 5`, so in case of usage [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (no `<!DOCTYPE html ...>`).

**UPDATED 3**: Based on the question/answer I posted two suggestions to trirand: [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/explicitly-deny-the-usage-of-jqgrid-in-quirk-mode/#p26754) and [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/setting-font-size-in-ui-jqgrid-css/#p26757). Both suggesting was accepted and are the parts of jqGrid now (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/18930eff8a3984519607a872436713d6326ca897) and [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/cd019fc800ec29c44d0b2918f6d9b1395d9b3f0d)). So the user of the next version should don't have the described problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But when I tried `.ui-jqgrid {position: relative; font-size:11px !important;}` it just changed the font size of the header. The data in the table as well as the nav bar stayed large. I tried your alternate proposal and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Dave: The reason could be only **one more CSS** which you use. Just open IE Developer Tools with F12. Choose "HTML" tab. Press refresh (F5) to load page data. Press Ctrl-B or use Find menu and then select any cell of the grid. On the right part scroll the styles and find the CSS style where `font-size` is still active. It's the CSS which make the problem in your case. In my demo it will be `.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }` like I described in my answer.

Comment: That I understand. What I can't seem to figure out is how to override that value for just the jqGrid, but for the entire jqGrid. Your answer regarding using `!important` works perfect in your 3rd example and that is what I'm looking for. But when I do that it only formats the header of the table with the correct font-size.

Comment: For clarification, I'm wanting to know how to modify the jqGrid to always override other font-size settings no matter where they come from.

Comment: @Dave: `!important` is the setting. Do you tried `.ui-jqgrid { font-size: 11px !important; }`? Of cause if you have another CSS style which will be also applied and which has `!important` then you will still have to analyse the problem. In my opinion you should analyse the problem in any way. It's not so complex and I described you step by step what you need to do. Because it's really simple you can send me URL which reproduce the problem or send me per email the project which reproduce it.

Comment: I did try the `.ui-jqgrid { font-size: 11px !important; }`, and like I said it works for the header of the table. Just not the rest of the table. I'll look through my other css files tonight (the only ones I'm using are jquery, jqueryui and jqgrid) and make sure there isn't another `!important` that I'm missing.

Comment: @Dave: Looking through CSS is not effective way. Some styles can be added at the execution time by some JavaScripts. So you should use debugging tools like I described before to see **effective** styles used.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I was referring to. I am using the Chrome tool to analyze currently loaded styles.

Comment: @Dave: See UPDATED part of my answer.

Comment: I see that. So I looked at my project site and couldn't find anything overwriting the entire table, so I focused on one of the random cells. Looking at Computed Styles I see that font-size is set to 16px. Not sure why since the only thing it shows as being used is the 11px statement. See my screenshot up in the original post.

Comment: @Dave: It looks like that you have some "User Agent Style Sheets" of Chrome which has `table { font-size: medium }` and which *overwrite* font size. First of all you should test in *other* web browser, second you should examine your **full HTML page** inclusive `<!DOCTYPE html ...` (do you have included the line I hope). You should validate it in http://validator.w3.org. You should also examine plugins which you installed in the web browser.

Comment: @Dave: I read your email and wrote "UPDATED 2" part of my answer.

Comment: @Dave: There are some changes which I described in  "**UPDATED 3**" part of my answer.